# Paypal Direct Payment API

Tags: php, shopping-cart, paypal

Is there any up to date documentation out there on how to use the Paypal direct payment API?

Answer (score 4):

I found a working demo code for Paypal direct payment API : http://www.mmtutorialvault.com/paypal-pro-integration-in-php/

Answer (score 1):

Google found this:
https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/library_code

wont that do?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using PHP this component is worth a look. It costs $30, but I found it was well worth the time and effort saved. http://www.binpress.com/app/php-paypal-api-class/20

Answer (score 1):

PayPal provides various payment related operations using the /payment resource and related sub-resources. Use /payment for direct credit card payments and PayPal account payments.

URI: https://api.paypal.com/v1/payments/payment

Create a payment: POST /v1/payments/payment

For more information, refer:

https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/api/#create-a-payment

Answer (score 0):

On the [Paypal PHP SDK](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-PHP-SDK) repo Paypal says :

> Direct Credit Card Support
>
> **Important: The PayPal REST API no longer supports new direct credit card integrations**. Please instead consider Braintree Direct; which is, PayPal's preferred integration solution for accepting direct credit card payments in your mobile app or website. Braintree, a PayPal service, is the easiest way to accept credit cards, PayPal, and many other payment methods.

So Paypal recommands to use Braintree Direct. More details on [Braintree direct page](https://www.braintreepayments.com/products/braintree-direct)